# I unable to understand

Tags: java, if-statement

> I found this but unable to understand the if condition used in this program.:if(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek()[0] == i)

```
class Solution {

public String removeDuplicates(String s, int k) {
    Stack<int[]> stack = new Stack();
    for(char i : s.toCharArray()){
        if(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek()[0] == i){
            stack.peek()[1]++;
        }else{
            stack.push(new int[]{i,1});
        }
        
        if(stack.peek()[1] == k){
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        int len = stack.peek()[1];
        char ch = (char)stack.pop()[0];
        while(len>0){
            result.append(ch);
            len--;
        }
    }
    
    return result.reverse().toString();
    
}
```

}

Comment: `EmptyStackException - if this stack is empty.`

Comment: Hey Can you tell me about this: stack.peek()[0] == i

Comment: Think about what is being stored. Yes `int arrays` So it is looking at the first element of the returned int array.

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Stack.peek() method in Java is used to retrieve or fetch the first element of the Stack or the element present at the top of the Stack. The element retrieved does not get deleted or removed from the Stack.

**Syntax:**

```
STACK.peek()
```

**Parameters:** The method does not take any parameters.

Return Value: The method returns the element at the top of the Stack else returns NULL if the Stack is empty.

**Exception:** The method throws EmptyStackException if the stack is empty.

So here is your expression.

```
if(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek()[0] == i)
```

You have stack declared to contain array. So it will fetch the array at the top of stack and 0th index element from the top most array.

So if your stack is like this,

```
Stack
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 5, 8, 9]

stack.peek()[0] = 1;
```